# Specs2 ForEach context with execution env

Tags: scala, unit-testing, specs2

I'm executing my unit tests with specs2 library. At the moment I'm using ForEach context to inject my database into unit tests like this example:

```
trait DatabaseContext extends ForEach[Transaction] {
  // you need to define the "foreach" method
  def foreach[R: AsResult](f: Transaction => R): Result = {
    val transaction = openDatabaseTransaction
    try AsResult(f(transaction))
    finally closeDatabaseTransaction(transaction)
  }

  // create and close a transaction
  def openDatabaseTransaction: Transaction = ???

  def closeDatabaseTransaction(t: Transaction) = ???
}
```

That approach let me write my tests like this:

```
"test 1" >> { t: Transaction =>
    println("use the transaction")
    ok
}
```

My problem is that I need also the `ExecutionEnv` in my test because I'm using `specs2` future matchers expectations.

```
"test 1" >> { implicit env: ExecutionEnv =>
   Future(1) must be_==( 0 ).await
}
```

How can I combine both approaches so that I can get access to the execution env in my test using ForEach?
I've already tried using this code but it does not compile

```
"test 1" >> { implicit env: ExecutionEnv =>
    new DatabaseContext { t: Transaccion =>
      myFuture must be_==( "some result" ).await
    }
}
```

I'll appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you all very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a recent version of specs2 (3.6.5 is the latest one) you can simply ["inject" the execution environment as a class member](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.5/org.specs2.guide.Environment.html):

```
class MySpec(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification {
  ...
}
```

Then you can use your `DatabaseContext` as before.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to chain them together this way:

```
  "test with env and transaction" >> { implicit env: ExecutionEnv => t:Transaction =>
    Future(1) must be_==( 0 ).await
    println("use the transaction")
    ok
  }
```